# What is the 'valid specification of the columns' needed for sklearn classifier pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**Goal:** Predict the result based on int and object based features with sklearn.

I am using the following dataset from Kaggle: [Soccer Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer)

Here's my notebook: [Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/kevinlwebb/applying-simple-ml?scriptVersionId=33442699)

Libraries

- scikit-learn == 0.22.1

I have created a pipeline which almost works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Read the data
df = total_df.copy()

# Remove rows with missing target
df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['result'], inplace=True)

# Separate target from predictors
y = df.result         
X = df.drop(['result'], axis=1)

# Break off validation set from training data
X_train_full, X_test_full, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                                train_size=0.8,
                                                                test_size=0.2,
                                                                random_state=0)

integer_features = list(X.columns[X.dtypes == 'int64'])
#continuous_features = list(X.columns[X.dtypes == 'float64'])
categorical_features = list(X.columns[X.dtypes == 'object'])

# Keep selected columns only
my_cols = categorical_features + integer_features
X_train = X_train_full[my_cols].copy()
X_test = X_test_full[my_cols].copy()

integer_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [
   ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
   ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
   transformers=[
       ('ints', integer_transformer, integer_features),
       ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

base = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                     ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])

# Preprocessing of training data, fit model 
base.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I received an error:

`ValueError: No valid specification of the columns. Only a scalar, list or slice of all integers or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed`

Here is the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _determine_key_type(key, accept_slice)
    255         try:
--> 256             return dtype_to_str[type(key)]
    257         except KeyError:

KeyError: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.quoted_name'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-702987dff390> in <module>
     47 
     48 # Preprocessing of training data, fit model
---> 49 base.fit(X_train, y_train)
     50 
     51 base.predict(X_test)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    348             This estimator
    349         """
--> 350         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    351         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    313                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    314                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 315                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    316             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    317             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    726     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    727         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 728             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    729         else:
    730             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    514         self._validate_transformers()
    515         self._validate_column_callables(X)
--> 516         self._validate_remainder(X)
    517 
    518         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _validate_remainder(self, X)
    316         if (hasattr(X, 'columns') and
    317                 any(_determine_key_type(cols) == 'str'
--> 318                     for cols in self._columns)):
    319             self._df_columns = X.columns
    320 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    316         if (hasattr(X, 'columns') and
    317                 any(_determine_key_type(cols) == 'str'
--> 318                     for cols in self._columns)):
    319             self._df_columns = X.columns
    320 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _determine_key_type(key, accept_slice)
    275     if isinstance(key, (list, tuple)):
    276         unique_key = set(key)
--> 277         key_type = {_determine_key_type(elt) for elt in unique_key}
    278         if not key_type:
    279             return None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <setcomp>(.0)
    275     if isinstance(key, (list, tuple)):
    276         unique_key = set(key)
--> 277         key_type = {_determine_key_type(elt) for elt in unique_key}
    278         if not key_type:
    279             return None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _determine_key_type(key, accept_slice)
    256             return dtype_to_str[type(key)]
    257         except KeyError:
--> 258             raise ValueError(err_msg)
    259     if isinstance(key, slice):
    260         if not accept_slice:

ValueError: No valid specification of the columns. Only a scalar, list or slice of all integers or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:** Error states 'only a scalar, list or slice of all integers or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed'. `integer_features` and `categorical_features` are lists containing only strings names of columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used list for integer_features and categorical features whereas Transformer requires Index type.

```
categorical_features = X.select_dtypes(include="object").columns
integer_features = X.select_dtypes(exclude="object").columns
```

Changing this,will solve your error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the `transformers` of `ColumnTransformer`, turns out you cannot use a list of column name strings for `integer_features` or `categorical_features`. If you change them to lists of the numeric column indices, meaning something like `integer_features = [5,6]` and `categorical_features = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (i.e. don't substitute list with its name, paste its contents):

```
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("passthrough_numeric", "passthrough",
            ["col1", "col2", "col3"]),
    ],
    remainder="drop",
)
```

*More info*

The problem with `ColumnTransformer` is not that it requires column index numbers (it does accept column names too), but that it only accepts column names in an "anonymous" list created inside the `ColumnTransformer` definition... or else raises the `ValueError` when the list is passed as its name!

SQL comes to mind, with those long lists of column names that analysts used to create e.g. in Excel, complete with leading commas, and pasted to their SQL client, effectively as a single string...